# Not possible to connect with remote device using Socket API (kotlin, java) with public IP adress of this device

Tags: java, kotlin, sockets, networking, ip

Is it possible to connect with remote Android device with the socket API (Kotlin) by using the public IP address of this device? I wrote code working well in internal network, I use the private IP address of the device and everything work well. When I switch the network to LTE on both devices (sever and client), it's impossible to establish connection between them by using their public IP addresses (the public IP addresses I got from https://www.whatismyip.com/).

I wonder what can be a problem:

- Socket API cannot establish connection between devices outside internal network?
- my phone sevice provider (LTE provider) blocks that kind of connection?
- problem with firewall?
- or something else?

Comment: probably [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)

Comment: The server needs to bind to its local address; the client needs to connect to the server's public address; there needs to be a forwarding rule in the server's router/NAT box.